# Jenkins groovy : set environment variable between quote

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am trying to set a environment variable to a http request header.
For example

```
""" --header 'Authorization: "${auth}"' """
```

But probaly due to the quote '...', the ${auth} is not correctly set.

A simple example:

```
job(jobName) {
    wrappers {
        environmentVariables {
            env('auth', 'something I want to set')
        }
    }
    steps {
        shell(''' echo "${auth}" ''')
    }
}
```

my test:

```
shell(''' echo "${auth}" ''') --> correctly echo
shell(''' echo '"${auth}"' ''') --> not echo correctly
shell(""" echo '"${auth}"' """) --> not echo correctly
```

Comment: `println(""" --header 'Authorization: "${auth}"' """)​` prints `--header 'Authorization: "test"'` here. Not to you?

Comment: No, it show `No such property: auth for class: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.step.StepContext` error

Answer (score 1):

per-character escaping: `\"`

```
~ auth="test"
~ echo "\"${auth}\""
"test"
```

concatenation: `'"'` `${auth}` `'"'`

```
~ echo '"'${auth}'"'
"test"
```

Comment: It will output `No such property: auth for class: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.step.StepContext` error, probably because I am using dsl's shell command?